How to prevent the event of bootstrap accordion if the child element is clicked in accordion-button
I want to stop the native functionality of the accordion if the icons of the accordion button are pressed if not then it should be collapsed as usual

HTML
    <div class="accordion" >
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                <div class="accordion-button"  data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panel_collapse_1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panel_collapse_1">
                   <div class="test2">
                   
                    <span id="shipment__trackingNumber" onclick="preventAccordionCollapse(event)"> 785XXXXXXXX</span>
                         
                    <span id="shipment__status" onclick="preventAccordionCollapse(event)">Out for delivery</span>
                    
                    <span id="shipment__view" class="prevent-collapse" onclick="preventAccordionCollapse(event)">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25" fill="none">
                        <path d="M19.504 11.4684C19.8791 11.9238 20.0666 12.1514 20.0666 12.498C20.0666 12.8447 19.8791 13.0723 19.504 13.5276C18.132 15.1934 15.106 18.2948 11.5934 18.2948C8.08085 18.2948 5.05474 15.1934 3.68276 13.5276C3.30774 13.0723 3.12024 12.8447 3.12024 12.498C3.12024 12.1514 3.30774 11.9238 3.68276 11.4684C5.05474 9.80269 8.08085 6.70129 11.5934 6.70129C15.106 6.70129 18.132 9.80269 19.504 11.4684Z" fill="#164B7D" fill-opacity="0.24"/>
                        <path d="M11.5936 15.396C13.1943 15.396 14.4919 14.0983 14.4919 12.4976C14.4919 10.8969 13.1943 9.59924 11.5936 9.59924C9.99284 9.59924 8.69519 10.8969 8.69519 12.4976C8.69519 14.0983 9.99284 15.396 11.5936 15.396Z" fill="#164B7D"/>
                      </svg>
                    </span>
                    <span id="shipment__edit" onclick="preventAccordionCollapse(event)">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19" fill="none">
                        <path opacity="0.15" d="M3.02441 15.1221H6.0488L13.6098 7.56115L10.5854 4.53676L3.02441 12.0977V15.1221Z" fill="#164B7D"/>
                        <path d="M9.07319 15.1221H15.5M13.6098 7.56115L15.8781 5.29285L12.8537 2.26846L10.5854 4.53676M13.6098 7.56115L6.0488 15.1221H3.02441V12.0977L10.5854 4.53676M13.6098 7.56115L10.5854 4.53676" stroke="#164B7D" stroke-width="1.13415" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                      </svg>
                    </span>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </h2>
              <div id="panel_collapse_1" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

Javascript
function preventAccordionCollapse(event) {   
    if ($(event.target).closest('.prevent-collapse').length > 0) {
        
        event.preventDefault;
       
    }
    
}


Nesting clickable elements is nasty - HTML itself forbids it for good reason, so please avoid, if at all possible. In a scenario like this, I would put the two clickable icons outside of the button itself, and position them absolute, to get them into the desired position. If the actual button content could potentially run so wide, that the absolute positioned icons could overlap - then apply an appropriate margin or padding on the right, so that the button content can break into multiple lines, without causing overlaps.

Or make .accordion-header a flexbox container, so that the button and icons (still placed outside of the button in the DOM) can reside next to each other.

@CBroe  "Thank you so much for providing the solution. It worked perfectly."
